# PHP - Detecting duplicate values in a nested array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm using an API which returns some JSON that I output in PHP.

PHP

```
$result = $api->sendRequest("getUsers", $inputParameters);
$output = json_decode($result, true);
```

An example of an array returned by the API. I can print out specific field values fine, but I can't figure out how to write a simple if statement that indicates whether or not there are duplicate names within the query result, specifically duplicate [fullName] fields as seen below.

```
Array
(
    [status] => Array
        (
            [request] => getUsers
            [recordsTotal] => 3
            [recordsInResponse] => 3
        )

    [records] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [fullName] => Smith, Tom
                    [firstName] => Tom
                    [lastName] => Smith

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [fullName] => Jones, Bill
                    [firstName] => Bill
                    [lastName] => Jones
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [fullName] => Smith, Tom
                    [firstName] => Tom
                    [lastName] => Smith
                )

        )

)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you doing with this array ? Inserting in a table ? If so, I'd recommend that you would check if that value is already inserted.

Comment: Do these users have unique id's associated with them. Just curious, but _Tom Smith_ seems like it could be a fairly common name. Can you be absolutely sure these are not different users?...

Comment: @1nflktd Nope, just printing out specific values to HTML. So if there are duplicate [fullName] results, I want to print out a simple line of text indicating that duplicates were detected.

Comment: @War10ck They do have unique User IDs associated with them but I left them out for the sake of simplicity. Anyway, the IDs aren't really relevant, I just need to know if there are duplicate names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but maybe try something like

```
function dupeCheck($array, $attribute = 'fullName') {
    $list = array();
    foreach($array['records'] as $value) {
        if(in_array($value[$attribute], $list))
            return true;
        $list[] = $value[$attribute];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Just iterating over the records, we maintain a list of values of whatever attribute, once it finds one that was already in the array, returns true.

Then just:

```
if(!dupeCheck($output, 'fullName')) { // no dupes in the API response }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$data['records'] = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $data['records'])));
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php) and slightly modified.

Comment: Thanks Chief, CJ's answer above seemed to work best.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create an array whose keys will be the fullnames of the entris you've seen so far:

```
$names = array();
foreach ($output['records'] as $entry){
    If (isset($names[$entry['fullname']]){
        // do some error processing
        echo "'${entry['fullname']}' is a duplicate";
    }
    $names[$entry['fullname']] = $entry;
}
```

You should have all the unique entries in `$names`.

Comment: No problem, glad you got an answer.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a lot of built in array functions to help with operations like this. You could try the following:

```
$names = array_column($output['records'], "fullName");
if(count(array_unique($names)) < count($names)) {
    ... /* handle duplicate values here */
}
```

In addition, `$names` contains a unique array of all the `fullName` columns from the original array for easy access and traversing. You can use this inside the above `if` statement to determine which names are duplicates like so:

```
$names_count = array_count_values($names);
foreach($names_count as $key => $value) {
    if(value > 1) {
        $dupes[] = $key;
    }
}
```

**References:**

[PHP Array Functions](http://www.php.net//manual/en/ref.array.php)

[`array_column()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

[`array_unique()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

[`array_count_values()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)